# Change color of current selected element sidebar

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sidebar with site pages. I want to change the color of a currently selected page when clicked, assign the class is-active to the currently selected item, and remove it from all the others.
Here is the HTML:

```
<aside id="side-bar" class="sidebar">
        <h3>Pages</h3>
        <nav class="menu">
            <a onclick="changeColor()"  class="menu-item is-active">page 1</a>
            <a onclick="changeColor()"  class="menu-item">page 2</a>
            <a onclick="changeColor()"  class="menu-item">page 3</a>
        </nav>
</aside>
```

And CSS:

```
.sidebar .menu .menu-item:hover,
.sidebar .menu .menu-item.is-active {
    color: #f1672c;
    border-right: 6px solid #f1672c;
}
```

Each  element has the function change color that should take all the  elements, remove the is-active class from previous selected element and add to the curent clicked element.

```
function changeColor(){
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item")
    links.map(classList.remove("is-active"))
    this.classList.add("is-active")
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the idea that page 1 always starts as selected?

Comment: yes, the first page starts selected, and I want that is-active class to move to the next selected page and removed from previous

Answer (score 2):

That `changeColor()` is not necessary....

```js
const pages = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");

pages.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', active_item);
})

function active_item () {
  pages.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.remove('is-active');
  });
  this.classList.add('is-active');
}
```

```css
.is-active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<aside id="side-bar" class="sidebar">
        <h3>Pages</h3>
        <nav class="menu">
            <a class="menu-item is-active">page 1</a>
            <a class="menu-item">page 2</a>
            <a class="menu-item">page 3</a>
        </nav>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the reference of current element with `this`.

```js
function changeColor(el){
    document.querySelector(".menu-item.is-active").classList.remove("is-active")
    el.classList.add("is-active")
}
```

```css
.sidebar .menu .menu-item:hover,
.sidebar .menu .menu-item.is-active {
    color: #f1672c;
    border-right: 6px solid #f1672c;
}
```

```html
<aside id="side-bar" class="sidebar">
        <h3>Pages</h3>
        <nav class="menu">
            <a onclick="changeColor(this)"  class="menu-item is-active">page 1</a>
            <a onclick="changeColor(this)"  class="menu-item">page 2</a>
            <a onclick="changeColor(this)"  class="menu-item">page 3</a>
        </nav>
</aside>
```